# Java NIO Redirect connection

Tags: java, networking, nio

i'm trying to redirect a connection to another server with nio,
Here is my code, i think that the problem is the ByteBuffer.rewind() because this code redirect the data but in a strange way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ServerSocketChannel proxyServer = ServerSocketChannel.open();

    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

        SocketChannel clientChannel = proxyServer.accept();
        clientChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        ByteBuffer uploadBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 5);
        ByteBuffer downloadBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 5);

        try {
            SocketChannel serverChannel = SocketChannel.open();
            serverChannel.connect(
                new InetSocketAddress(
                    "another server"
                    , 80
                )
            );

            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

                // Client -> Server
                if (clientChannel.read(uploadBuffer) < 0) {
                    throw new EOFException();
                }

                uploadBuffer.rewind(); // <- maybe is this the error
                while (uploadBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    serverChannel.write(uploadBuffer);
                }

                // Server -> Client
                if (serverChannel.read(downloadBuffer) < 0) {
                    throw new EOFException();
                }

                downloadBuffer.rewind(); // <- maybe is this?
                while (downloadBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    clientChannel.write(downloadBuffer);
                }

                // Buffer reset
                downloadBuffer.clear();
                uploadBuffer.clear();
            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            clientChannel.close();
        }
    }
    proxyServer.close();
}
```

Maybe i have to use flip?

Comment: What do you mean by *this code redirect the data but in a strange way.*. Please be more specific!

Comment: @suman i mean that the downloaded/uploaded byte buffer have some problem because they are not in the same order when sended or recived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SocketChannel.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) returns the number of bytes received.  There is no guarantee the method has filled up the ByteBuffer.

You are checking whether the returned count is negative, but then you discard it.  What you need to do is pay attention the ByteBuffer's [position](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position--) after each read.  As you suspected, the [flip()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) method takes care of that for you.  A typical usage is to read some bytes into a ByteBuffer, then flip that buffer so it is ready to be read by some other code.

So, yes, changing each of your `rewind()` calls to `flip()` should solve your problem.